# Bundling import es6 modules expressions across all javascript files

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Let's say I have multiple javascript files, along with several node modules, and in each file I do something like this:

```
import 'node_module_a'
import 'node_module_b'
import 'node_module_c'
```

I find myself repeating this same code across all my javascript files, so I'm wondering is there a compact way (like bundling) to add all this to a single file, and just import from that?

Like:

in all_the_things.js:

```
import 'node_module_a'
import 'node_module_b'
import 'node_module_c'
```

Then add only this line in all javascript files:

```
import * from 'all_the_things.js'
```

I tried reading some documentation to give me ideas, but I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Yes, just create your own module.. with those lines in, and instead import that one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no idea I literally wrote the answer in the question. I tried all kinds of stuff, except what I posted. When I tried it, it worked.

If you put

in all_the_things.js:

```
import 'node_module_a'
import 'node_module_b'
import 'node_module_c'
```

then you do this in the caller js file:

```
import 'all_the_things'
```

it will import all the nodes. Also, I found out if you put those imports in a parent file, loading only once, it will be viewed by other child components.